# OWASP ZAP - a list of error messages

Tags: zap

Where in source code ZAP I can find list or template of response errors like MySQL-Error, PHP-Error from test sites? Do not the problems mentioned by the ZAP in the results.

Answer (score -1):

The ZAP active scan rules are defined in the following locations, depending on the status of the relevant rules:

- Release quality:  [master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrules](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/beta/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesBeta)
- Beta quality:     [branches/beta/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesBeta](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/beta/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesBeta)
- Alpha quality:    [branches/alpha/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesAlpha](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/alpha/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/ascanrulesAlpha)

For future reference we may restructure the repo in which case all of the rules might end up in the master or maybe develop branch.

For more details about the active rules see http://zaproxy.blogspot.fr/2014/04/hacking-zap-4-active-scan-rules.html

You can also ask specific questions on the ZAP developer group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-develop